# How to retrieve a count of items sold from total orders for one day in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Currently I am just using FirebaseListAdapter in Android to display a list of Orders.

My Orders are stored like this within firebase database.

```
-completed
 -KsRHO1sLcVxKtVMec3o
      dateCreated: 1503713136950
      orderItems: 0
                description: “Fries”
                id: 101
            1
                description: “Small Burger“
                id: 1023
```

I would like to create a chart of items sold

How could i go through the list of completed orders and count the amount of fries that have been sold on a certain date?

I would like the data to be returned like this

```
{
    “Item”: “fries”,
    “amountSold”: 34
  }
{
    “Item”: “Small Burger”,
    “amountSold”: 4
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase function makes it easy to do that. You would need to go through your data and count the sold items (children count essentially) and then write the sum to your destination location.

See [Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count) for an example of such Firebase function for counting children. The code that counts the correct value depends on the structure of your data but essentially is the same. You have to get the data, count children and upload the sum back to database. All happens within one Firebase function. Your function can be triggered by onWrite so that any new write or update triggers it.

Make sure to use transactions when writing the sum back to database because the value of that sum can change as you are writing it to database.

Answer (score 0):

All You can do is create filed for date  like created date and end date make save same date in both and then query on child according to date.!

```
var startDate = 14-02-17;
var endDate = 14-02-17;

ref.orderByChild("childID").startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate)
      .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
}


var query = firebase.database().ref('child').orderByChild('startDate').equalTo(startDate);
```